# Problem selecting an item after building the select options with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-select

I use this javascript to select a specific option (the option value being specified within a hidden element):

```
$("select").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var source = 'input:hidden[name=select_'+id+']';
    if ($(source).length) {
        var selected = $(source).val();
        $(this).val(selected).change();
    }
});
```

This works fine when the options are hard coded in the HTML source.

I now need to populate the options with an AJAX call, I use the below method:

```
select : function(ctrl,id) {
    var call = '/'+ctrl+'/'+$("#auth input[name=verify]").val();
    $.getJSON(call, function(result) {
        $.each(result, function() {
            $('#'+id).append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.title));
        });
    });
},
```

I process the select method (AJAX) on page load, and the options populate fine. But when I then try to select the desired option, the browser defaults to the first option.

I have tested what is happening by sticking some alerts around the code as thus:

```
    alert($(this).val(selected));       // A
    alert($(this).val());               // B
    $(this).val(selected).change();
    alert($(this).val());               // C
```

When the options are hard coded I get A=3, B=null, C=3 i.e. it works
When the options are populated via AJAX I get A=3, B=null, C=null i.e. it fails

I am guessing that I need to trigger some kind of change() event after populating the option list with AJAX. I have tried (a bit overkill I know):

```
$('#'+id).append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.title).change());
```

&

```
$('#'+id).append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.title)).change();
```

Any ideas? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Although I was triggering the code in the correct order (in theory), because of javascripts event driven behaviour the AJAX call was not completing until after my select initialisation had finished. So I moved the code to set the selected option into the AJAX call and voila.

```
select : function(ctrl,id) {
var call = '/'+ctrl+'/'+$("#auth input[name=verify]").val();
$.getJSON(call, function(result) {
    $.each(result, function() {
        $('#'+id).append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.title));
    });
    var source = 'input:hidden[name=select_'+id+']';
    if ($(source).length) {
        var selected = $(source).val();
        $('#'+id).val(selected).change();
    }
});
```